# Android P-9.0.0_r53 Logcat Main Buffer Exceed Defined Size

Tags: android, c++, buffer, android-source, logcat

In our Android AOSP, Logcat main buffer exceed the defined size no matter what is the size of it. 
And `logcat -c` or other commands doesn't works. after that it gives `read: unexpected EOF!`
I was looking in the source-codes of `logcat.cpp` couldn't find any particular thing. Do you know why this problem occurs ?

`adb logcat -g` outputs:

```
eg: when issue is happening (read: unexpected EOF!)
main: ring buffer is 4Mb (20Mb consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
system: ring buffer is 4Mb (257Kb consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
crash: ring buffer is 4Mb (13Kb consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and solution.

> the main reason of the problem is setting of system date to older
>   dates than the initial date. Time doesn't matter though.

In my case:

> I don't know why but the system initial date is always +1 day than
>   now. When the system date is synced with the current date ( which is
>   older date for the system initial date), buffer start to overflow and
>   clear buffer commands doesn't work.
>
> You can test with setting the date to the next day or next dates. You
>   can check buffer sizes and consumed with  ´adb logcat -g´ or ´adb
>   logcat -b all -g´ and try to clear with ´adb logcat -c´.